# K Framework: Cannot convert to subtype

Tags: kframework

I'm trying evaluate Expressions to Values (Exps ::= Values) for function calls.

Here's a simple example:

```
module ERL-SYNTAX

  imports INT-SYNTAX
  imports STRING
  syntax Atom ::= "main" | "f"
  syntax Exp ::=  Atom | Int
  syntax Exp ::= Exp "(" Exps ")"             [seqstrict]
  syntax Exps ::= List{Exp, ","}              [seqstrict]

endmodule

module ERL-CONFIGURATION

  imports ERL-SYNTAX
  imports MAP

  syntax Value ::=  Atom | Int | "{" Values "}"
  syntax Values ::= List{Value, ","}
  syntax Exp ::= Value
  syntax Exps ::= Values
  syntax KResult ::= Value
  syntax KResult ::= Values

  configuration <cfg color="yellow">
                  <k color="green"> $PGM:Exp </k>
                  <fundefs> //some default function definitions
                    .Map (f |-> 5 , .Exps 
                    main |-> f ( 2 , 3 , .Exps ) , .Exps )
                  </fundefs>
                </cfg>
endmodule

module ERL

  imports ERL-SYNTAX
  imports ERL-CONFIGURATION

  //rule .Exps => .Values
  rule <k>F:Atom(_:Values) =>  L ...</k>
       <fundefs>...  F |-> L ...</fundefs>

endmodule
```

This gets stuck at

> .Exps ~> #freezer_(_)*ERL-SYNTAX1* ( main )

So I tried with this rule: .Exps => .Values to evaluate main().

To me, the strange thing is that this time heating 3 is ok:

> .Values ~> #freezer_,**ERL-SYNTAX1* ( 3 ) ~> #freezer*,_*ERL-SYNTAX1* ( 2 ) ~> ...

will be

> 3 , .Values ~> #freezer_,_*ERL-SYNTAX1* ( 2 ) ~> ..

but here it gets stuck again.

How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the productions for `Exps` and `Vals` in the same module and give them the same `klabel` attribute. This will make them overload one another, at which point in time, the fact that .Values is a KResult should solve your problem.